# Register Application With Zapier

Tags: zapier

I am developing an application from where users can create zaps and later those zaps can be searched in Zapier if I will connect my application from Zapier.

Now question is how to get the  Integration Key that can be used when connecting to Zapier  by clicking "Connect an Account"

after this how I can search for the zaps that I created in my application? 
do I need to use any api to create those zaps in zapier?

Answer (score 1):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

If you add a private app to Zapier, you'll be able to use it for your zaps immediately. If you want others to use it, you'll want to go through the process describe [here](https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/app-lifecycle/), where you invite users, submit for activation, etc.

We have a few guides to get you going:

- [UI Quickstart](https://platform.zapier.com/quickstart/introduction)
- [CLI Quickstart](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli#quick-setup-guide)